# mmap memory kernel space to user space - too slow, any improvements?

Tags: mmap, memcpy

In kernel driver, using remap_pfn_range to remap a physical memory block
`vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);`
`vma->vm_flags |= VMEM_FLAGS | VM_PFNMAP;`
`vma->vm_pgoff = phys >> PAGE_SHIFT;`
`remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff, vsize, vma->vm_page_prot);`
And in User space, using mmap to access,
`frame = mmap(NULL, addr, PROT_WRITE , MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, aligned);`
then use memcpy to move data.

It can only move data at 200MB/s. ( Intel i7 running Ubuntu22.04)
Am I missing any flags or that is the best it can get?

I am expecting better results. In the same user space, memcpy can do 2GB/s. But memcpy through mmap from kernel space to user space, it seems too slow.

Thank you
Tiger